# How to predict sentiment of a text by using word2Vec and deep learning model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, word2vec

I am trying to detect sentiment of tweets by using word2vec and some deep learning algorithms. Here is my model training codes :

```
word2VecValues = pd.read_csv(allVectorValuesPath, sep=",", skipinitialspace=True)
word2VecValues = convertLabelToFloat(word2VecValues)
word2VecValues = prepareDataSet(word2VecValues)

X = word2VecValues.iloc[:, :-1]
Y = word2VecValues.iloc[:, -1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=25, batch_size=10)

saveModel(model, "Word2Vec")

_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy * 100))
```

As you see, I have a csv file which contains word2vec vector values of each word of my corpus. I  am using it as data frame which is "word2VecValues".

I save my word2vec model after model training finished.
I want to load the model and predict sentiment of one text. However, I have little bit confusing about how I can get vector values of new text. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

you should find a dataset **annotated** with sentiment data, or annotate your own dataset which is quite time consuming. convert the text to batch of vectors using word2vec, feed the vectors to an lstm layer instead of a dense layer.
word2vec alone isn't enough for sentiment analysis.
and if you ask me since you're going to analyze twitter and Tweets are full of improvisations that don't fit into standard vocab of word2vec, you'd be better with fastText.

Comment: Thanks your advices. I will study on fastText